# Checkbutton Status Checking Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi im trying to write a piece of code on python that lists a value in a label depending how many checkbuttons are ticked. why isnt my code working?

```
var1=IntVar()
var2=IntVar()
var3=IntVar()



inlabel = StringVar()


label =  Label (the_window, height = 1,bg = "white",width = 30, textvariable = inlabel,font = ("arial",50,"normal")).pack()
def check():
    if(var1 == 0 and var2 == 0 and var3==1):
        inlabel.set("odd")
    if(var1 == 0 and var2 == 1 and var3==1):
        inlabel.set("even")
    if(var1 == 1 and var2 == 1 and var3==1):
        inlabel.set("odd")
    if(var1 == 0 and var2 == 1 and var3==0):
        inlabel.set("odd")
    if(var1 == 1 and var2 == 1 and var3==0):
        inlabel.set("even")
    if(var1 == 0 and var2 == 0 and var3==0):
        inlabel.set("null")
    if(var1 == 1 and var2 == 0 and var3==0):
        inlabel.set("odd")
    if(var1 == 1 and var2 == 0 and var3==1):
        inlabel.set("even")

check1 = Checkbutton(the_window, text= "Gamma",variable=var1,command=check)
check2 = Checkbutton(the_window, text= "Beta",variable=var2,command=check)
check3 = Checkbutton(the_window, text= "Alpha",variable=var3,command=check)
check1.pack(side=RIGHT)
check2.pack()
check3.pack(side=LEFT)
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Presumably you are using tkinter? If so, it would mentioning that in the question title and tags (otherwise it's not clear where `Checkbutton` etc are defined)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425467/cant-get-the-function-to-work-with-checkbuttons-using-tkinter

Comment: haha yep looks like it

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `get` and assign it to another variable instead of `var1`.
So something like this should work.

```
value1 = var1.get()
value2 = var2.get()
value3 = var3.get()
```

I assumed you defined your parent window (`the_window`) in your actual program.

Comment: Thanks and yes I did define the_window earlier :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the var.get(). Here's a working example in Python3.3.

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

class CheckB():
    def __init__(self, master, text):
        self.var = IntVar()
        self.text=text
        c = Checkbutton(
            master, text=text,
            variable=self.var,
            command=self.check)
        c.pack()

    def check(self):
        print (self.text, "is", self.var.get())


check1 = CheckB(root, text="Gamma")
check2 = CheckB(root, text="Beta")
check3 = CheckB(root, text="Alpha")
```

Hope that helped! - Ed